# How can I change the color of text if a Value is negative?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web application I'm working on that does addition between integers. I have two functions called **num1()** and **num2()** that get the two integers as input from the user. I want to change the resulting output text color if the sum of the two integers is negative. How do I do this with JavaScript?

I've seen a lot of jQuery examples, but I want to do this with solely JavaScript.

```
function addIntegers() {
        var sum = num1() + num2();
        if(sum < 0) {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML=
            "Result: " + sum;
        }

        else {
            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML=
            "Result: " + sum;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('display').style.color = 'red';`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM objects have a `.style` object that will let you set whatever you would like.  In your case, you're looking for the `color` property, so your function would look like this:

```
function addIntegers() {
    var sum = num1() + num2();
    var displayObj = document.getElementById('display');
    displayObj.innerHTML = "Result: " + sum; 
    if (sum < 0)
        displayObj.style.color = 'red'
    else 
        displayObj.style.color = 'green'
}
```

You'll notice I set the element in question to an object so you don't have to call `getElementById` multiple times.  Also, since you'll always be writing the sum, you can remove that from the `if` statement, as you only care about changing the color there.