# In JavaScript output in a currency format and change the font color depending on the output value

Tags: javascript, variables, output

I have many results being output from variables into spans, for example:

**JavaScript**
document.getElementById("ResultsSavingsPerDay").innerHTML = SavingsPerDay;

**HTML**

```
Savings per day: <span id="ResultsSavingsPerDay"></span> Thai Baht
```

which may display the result as something like: **4347.343543654**

How can I format the output to the currency to display as **4,347.34**? And if the output is a negative figure then change the font color to red also?

I have seen similar currency formats on Stack Overflow, but not changing the results within a span. It is this part that I am struggling with mainly.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: I did state **I have seen similar currency formats, but not changing the results of a span.**  meaning I have seen similar ways to change currency of various things such as the log outputs and input boxes, but not span outputs. So I disagree to it being a duplicate @mplungjan

Comment: See the  dupes One formats signed currency, the other sets the class or color. There are hundreds `var span = document.getElementById("SavingsPerDay"); span.innerHTML = formatMoney(SavingsPerDay); span.style.color=SavingsPerDay<0?"red":"black";`

Comment: I have tried searching on StackOverflow and Google searching through many other sites, but unable to find exactly what I am looking for, hence posting here. If there is a dupe, please link me to it relating to span currency formatting and not currency formatting in general.

Comment: The difference is `document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML=formatMoney(SavingsPerDay)` and `document.getElementById("myFormField").value=formatMoney(SavingsPerDay)` What is your specific issue with this difference?

Comment: Here is a solution based on the first dupe with the simple addition of a test for negative http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/1jvLgtfd/

Comment: Okay the JSFiddle solution works perfectly! Greatly appreciated. However because I have around 25 output spans on the page, how would I go about doing a **working** array similar to this? http://jsfiddle.net/Dayley/a9jqc2x8/1/

Comment: Call the function on the amount. NEVER have such a complicated calculation inside the loop: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/1jvLgtfd/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184368/discussion-between-dayley-and-mplungjan).

Comment: As you [seem to be confused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406187#comment832775_406187) about how the duplicates answer your question, for the formatting: `document.getElementById("ResultsSavingsPerDay").innerHTML = SavingsPerDay.toFixed(2);` (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/149099/3270037). For the colour [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29397972/3270037) is basically an exact duplicate of what you want, except using `ResultsSavingsPerDay` instead of `display` and `SavingsPerDay` instead of `sum`.